# Angular 2 pass variable from one component to another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

so I have one component that contains list array :

A component TS :

```
list = [
{name:Jhon},
{name: Pop}
]
```

A component html :

```
<h2>List :</h2>
<b-component></b-component> //how to pass list to B component here ?
```

B component html :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
{{list.name}}
</div>
```

**How to pass A component list to B component on tag ?**

Comment: Why don't you search for the question before you post it?

Comment: I searched but <app-item-list [list]="list"></app-item-list> doesnt work

Comment: here's a way to search for : https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srhs5x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

**Parent component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <hello [list]="list"></hello>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  list = ['abc', 'edf', 'ghi'];
}
```

**Child component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() list: string[];
}
```

Comment: what if I use lazy modules?

Comment: Your question has been answered, To learn more about lazy modules read the official docs or search Stackoverflow properly, you will find the answers for all your questions. but you cannot ask questions this way in this platform.

Answer (score 0):

In your **B component .ts file**, you have to define your list like :

```
@Input() list;
```

With this, you can use the list in the **B component html**.

Comment: what if I use lazy modules?

Comment: Lazy module? Can you elaborate? You question is about components. Why are you talking about lazy modules?